# Creating flexbox row with equal layouts *per line*

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve a flexbox, where the row will have the titles all lined up. Requirements:

1. The images won't always be the same height
2. The description won't always be the same height
3. The title could be 1 row, or 3 (depending on the length)

Here is a simple fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/youradds/r56j4uLe/6/

As you can see this is what you get:

[image]

This is more what I'm after:

[image]

My **SCSS** is:

```
#item-wrapper {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    .item-block {

    background: yellow;

        flex-grow: 0;
        width: 350px;
        margin: 2rem 1rem;

        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-content: center;
        align-items: center;

        .what-logo {

            img {
                max-height: 100%;
            }
        }

        .text-info {
            flex-grow: 1;

            .desc {
                padding: 1rem;
            }

            h2 {
                flex-grow: 0;
            }

        }


        .action-button {
            margin: 0 auto;
        }



    }
}

.pure-img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

..and test HTML:

```
<div id="item-wrapper">
    <div class="item-block">
        <div class="what-logo">
            <img src="https://bodywisegym.co.uk/2018/images/events/3/3-1562951826-3.png" class="pure-img">
        </div>
        <div class="text-info">
            <h2>Zydrunas Savickas Seminar</h2>
            <div class="desc">Bodywise Gym and Studios are proud to announce we are bringing the greatest strongman Zydrunas Savickas (Big Z) to Horsham for a seminar.</div>
        </div>
        <a href="https://yogida.co.uk/collections/events/products/zydrunas-savickas-big-z-seminar" class="action-button">Find out more &raquo;</a>
    </div>

    <div class="item-block">
        <div class="what-logo">
            <img src="https://bodywisegym.co.uk/2018/images/events/7/7-1562936970-7.jpg" class="pure-img">
        </div>
        <div class="text-info">
            <h2>Class for mums</h2>
            <div class="desc">Join Quick HIIT</div>
        </div>
        <a href="" class="action-button">Find out more &raquo;</a>
    </div>

    <div class="item-block">
        <div class="what-logo">
            <img src="https://bodywisegym.co.uk/2018/images/events/6/6-1562936464-6.png" class="pure-img">
        </div>
        <div class="text-info">
            <h2>Gratitude Day</h2>
            <div class="desc">To spread the positivity you can bring a training partner along to workout with you or to attend one of our classes.</div>
        </div>
        <a href="" class="action-button">Find out more &raquo;</a>
    </div>

    <div class="item-block">
        <div class="what-logo">
            <img src="https://bodywisegym.co.uk/2018/images/events/4/4-1562951950-4.jpg" class="pure-img">
        </div>
        <div class="text-info">
            <h2>The experience of non-duality</h2>
            <div class="desc">Yoga & meditation workshop with Indian Spiritual Master Acharya Shree Shankar </div>
        </div>
        <a href="https://yogida.co.uk/collections/workshops" class="action-button">Find out more &raquo;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Important note:** This is a responsive design, so I can't set a height on the image div (i.e min-height 600px) because while this kind of sorts it on wider screens:

[image]

...but then on smaller screens, it scales down to 1 element per row - and this then means we have a silly amount of padding between the image and the title on the entries with smaller images:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could look for a visual compromise.

flex children do not align with flex children from another flex parent.

You may try  centering `tex-info` and `what-logo` and add an average min-height on `.desc`

Demo below, play it in full page to test behavior and visual.

```css
#item-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#item-wrapper .item-block {
  background: yellow;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 2rem 1rem;
  padding:2px;/* see me */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#item-wrapper .item-block .what-logo img {
  max-height: 100%;
}

#item-wrapper .item-block .text-info,
#item-wrapper .item-block .what-logo {/* update */
  margin-top: auto;
}

#item-wrapper .item-block .text-info .desc {
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 4em;/* 3 lines , average */
}

#item-wrapper .item-block .text-info h2 {text-align:center}

#item-wrapper .item-block .action-button {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.pure-img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="item-wrapper">
  <div class="item-block">
    <div class="what-logo">
      <img src="https://bodywisegym.co.uk/2018/images/events/3/3-1562951826-3.png" class="pure-img">
    </div>
    <div class="text-info">
      <h2>Zydrunas Savickas Seminar</h2>
      <div class="desc">Bodywise Gym and Studios are proud to announce we are bringing the greatest strongman Zydrunas Savickas (Big Z) to Horsham for a seminar.</div>
    </div>
    <a href="https://yogida.co.uk/collections/events/products/zydrunas-savickas-big-z-seminar" class="action-button">Find out more &raquo;</a>
  </div>

  <div class="item-block">
    <div class="what-logo">
      <img src="https://bodywisegym.co.uk/2018/images/events/7/7-1562936970-7.jpg" class="pure-img">
    </div>
    <div class="text-info">
      <h2>Class for mums</h2>
      <div class="desc">Join Quick HIIT</div>
    </div>
    <a href="" class="action-button">Find out more &raquo;</a>
  </div>

  <div class="item-block">
    <div class="what-logo">
      <img src="https://bodywisegym.co.uk/2018/images/events/6/6-1562936464-6.png" class="pure-img">
    </div>
    <div class="text-info">
      <h2>Gratitude Day</h2>
      <div class="desc">To spread the positivity you can bring a training partner along to workout with you or to attend one of our classes.</div>
    </div>
    <a href="" class="action-button">Find out more &raquo;</a>
  </div>

  <div class="item-block">
    <div class="what-logo">
      <img src="https://bodywisegym.co.uk/2018/images/events/4/4-1562951950-4.jpg" class="pure-img">
    </div>
    <div class="text-info">
      <h2>The experience of non-duality</h2>
      <div class="desc">Yoga & meditation workshop with Indian Spiritual Master Acharya Shree Shankar </div>
    </div>
    <a href="https://yogida.co.uk/collections/workshops" class="action-button">Find out more &raquo;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[forked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhk95afy/)

Comment: Thanks for that. I think thats a decent compromise. I was going to try and do it with Javascript, but the issue is you don't know how many show on each line (to try and work out the max height for that row). This looks good. Hopefully most of the images will be the same size (so the biggest thing is the title/desc sizes)